# When using the AngularFireMessaging it doesn't work, and I have the following error: 'Hn.messaging is not a function in angular-fire-compat-messaging

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am using AngularFireMessaging for push notifications in my Angular application. I created the following service.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseMessagingService {
    public constructor(private afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {}

    public listen(): void {
        if (!this.browserService.isBrowser) {
            return;
        }

        this.afMessaging.messages.subscribe();
    }
 }
```

I use the 'listen' method in app.component.ts. When I run the development environment, everything works fine. But when I switch to production, I get the following error: 'Hn.messaging is not a function in angular-fire-compat-messaging.' After some research, I found that the problem is caused by the 'buildOptimizer' setting in angular.json. In development, it's set to false, but when switching to production, it's set to true, and it breaks the method.

The firebase-messaging-sw.js file contains the following:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-messaging.js');

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    projectId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: '',
    appId: '',
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I have the app.module.ts like this.

```
imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireMessagingModule,
]
```

I can't find a solution without having to disable the buildOptimizer in production.

I've already tried updating the library versions.